# Use information from a promise programatically

Tags: javascript

I made a small webpage that takes information from the "Yahoo Weather" API and displays it in divs on the page.

This is the JS:

```js
const url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys';
let data = 1;

const getWeather = async function() {
 const fetchWeather = await fetch(url);
 const result = await fetchWeather.json();
 return data=result;
}

getWeather();

const showData = async function(info) {
 let html = '';
 const newInfo = info.query.results.channel.item.forecast.map((item, index) => {
  html += `<div id='item${index}'><p>Date: ${item.date}</p>`;
  html += `<p>Day: ${item.day}</p>`;
  html += `<p>Highest temp: ${item.high}</p>`;
  html += `<p>Lowest temp: ${item.low}</p></div>`;
 return html;
 });
}

const display = async function() {
 const info = await showData(data);
 weatherInfo.innerHTML = data;
}

display();
```

My goal is that when the page loads, it displays the information gathered from the promise returned by the API.

I get this error:**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined**

Basically as far as I understand, by the time the "display()" is invoked, the variable "data" doesn't have anything in it yet.

What I'm trying to achieve is that display() will only work after "data" is defined, but without a for loop or something like that.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You will have to `await getWeather` at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solutiuon:

```
const url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys';

const getWeather = async function() {
  const fetchWeather = await fetch(url);
  return await fetchWeather.json();
}

const showData = async function(info) {
  let html = '';
  info.query.results.channel.item.forecast.map((item, index) => {
    html += `<div id='item${index}'><p>Date: ${item.date}</p>`;
    html += `<p>Day: ${item.day}</p>`;
    html += `<p>Highest temp: ${item.high}</p>`;
    html += `<p>Lowest temp: ${item.low}</p></div>`;
  });
  return html;
}

const display = async function() {
  const data = await getWeather();
  const info = await showData(data);
  weatherInfo.innerHTML = info;
}

display();
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/1b0fpBji7y6sZPODPDjY?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I understand, by the time the "display()" is invoked, the variable "data" doesn't have anything in it yet.

Yes. Don't use a global `data` variable at all<sup>1</sup>. `getWeather` returns a promise that will fulfill with the data, so you know exactly when it becomes available:

```
getWeather().then(display);
```

with

```
async function getWeather () {
    const fetchWeather = await fetch(url);
    const result = await fetchWeather.json();
    return result; // drop the `data =` assignment
}

async function display(data) {
//                     ^^^^
    const info = await showData(data);
    weatherInfo.innerHTML = info;
}
```

Alternatively, especially when you don't want to use a `then` chain, just put `const data = await getWeather();` in the `display` function.

<sub>1: If you insist to store the data in the global scope because you want to use it in multiple places, put the *promise* for the data in the variable not the result itself.</sub>

Comment: Appreciate the help. Couple of issues though. Now the page displayed "[object Object]". Second, I'd love to understand why when I assign getWeather() to a variable, the variable's value is the promise with the data in it, instead of just the data. That's why I used "return data=result"

Comment: @danielv `getWeather` is an *asynchronous* function. Its result will become available *sometime later.* It's the same as for `fetch`, that's why you `await fetch` inside `getWeather`. So you'll have to `await getWeather`  too.

Comment: @danielv You had assigned `data` to the `innerHTML` not the `info` string that `showData` returned. Fixed in my answer.

Comment: @danielv `getWeather` is an `async function`, that means its body evaluation can wait for asynchronous things but in turn it returns *a promise for* whatever result (`return` value) the execution has when it's done. It can't immediately return the value that will be computed in the future.